# How to Convert RGB color code to HTML code in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a component for my task and am trying to get the color using color picker plugin in nativescript. The problem is that it showing the result in int format such as -899123 or -989.

I created a method and called it which giving me this result, See Code below:

```
import { ColorPicker } from 'nativescript-color-picker';

let picker = new ColorPicker();
export class MyComponent extends Observable {
public Background:ColorPicker;
@Output() MessageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
constructor(private page: Page) {
    this.Background = picker;
}
ShowColor() {
    this.Background
  .show('#fff000', 'RGB')
  .then(result => {
      console.log('color int: '+result);
    this.input.Background = result;

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in the documentation, use the `Color` module to convert color values from integer to hex or rgba.

```
import { Color } from 'tns-core-modules/Color';

....
const color = new Color(result);
console.log(color.hex); // will return hex code
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Great manoj, I just tried this code and it worked for me.

```
this.input.background = result; 
const color = new Color(this.input.background); 
this.input.background = color.hex; 
console.log(this.input.background);
```

I used result value in this.input.background because it was showing error when I tried to use const color = new Color(result); so it worked with above method.
Thanks a lot